# Form of verb after a preposition

Tags: prepositions, verb-forms

I've heard a grammar rule which is, if there is any verb followed by a preposition except the 'to' preposition, the verb must have a 'ing'.

As example, I've this sentence:

> I am going for playing.

Where the 'play' verb is in 'ing' form.

But in this sentence:

> I am going to play.

the 'play' verb is in normal form.

I just want to know that is the rule correct? If correct then is there any other exceptional preposition like 'to'?

Comment: That rule is not correct. Assuming it's a correct quote. No grammar rule would call _to_ a verb. So check the rule again. Make sure that's what it is. Grammar rules, like equations, hafta be ***exact***.

Comment: @JohnLawler The rule does not say that _to_ is a verb. It says that  if there is any verb after _to_, then the verb must be in main form which means the verb must be in _Present Form_.

Comment: Then the rule is improperl stated. It is true, at least given certain definitions of "preposition" that exclude complementizers like _to_, that few prepositions take infinitive complements, but in fact the preposition _to_ can take a gerund complement. _I was listening to Bill singing "La Cucaracha"_. Of course, one must distinguish between the complementizer _to_ and the preposition _to_, which are identical in shape and must be identified in context. This means the rule goes the wrong direction; it doesn't predict.

Comment: @JohnLawler In the _I was listening to Bill singing "La Cucaracha"_ sentence, there is a noune ( _Bill_ ) between _to_ preposition and _sing_ verb. So the rule does not work here.

Comment: Grammar rules are not stated in terms of what kinds of words can follow other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. Nobody know what type of word *to* is in the sentence:

- I am going to play.

A lot of people would just call it a particle (which means it's small and they don't know what it is). A small number of people would say that it's a verb. Some people say that it's a subordinator. However only a very, very small number of writers think it's a preposition. Those people that do think that it's a preposition, would argue that it is an exceptional preposition. It is not the same as the preposition *to* that we find in the sentence *I went to Paris*. This word is the same word we find in:

- To err is human.

Most people regard it as part of an infinitive construction. It always appears before a plain form of the verb.

Regarding your rule. This rule is slightly circular because in backwards traditional grammar people describe prepositions as words that come before nouns. These writers view a gerund as a kind of nouny form of a verb. The problem is that if you ask these people why a particular sentence has a verb which isn't a gerund after a preposition, they'll say it's because that word is not a preposition. However, if you ask them why the word is not a preposition, they'll say because it isn't followed by a nouny form of the verb. You get the picture? This is an indefensible position to take. The answer to your question is that it is a fairly good rule of thumb that when a preposition occurs before a non-finite verb (i.e. not before a full finite clause) the verb will be in the *--ing* form. However, there are some exceptions:

- He went **on** to become president.

Here we see the preposition *on* occurring before the *to*-infinitival, *to become*. There are other exceptions such as:

- I was just **about** to leave.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21038/discussion-on-answer-by-araucaria-form-of-verb-after-a-preposition).

Answer (score 2):

That rule works pretty well, but I think it's an accident of circumstances.  For a preposition that introduces a prepositional phrase, a nominal object has to follow the preposition.  Not a verb.  So if you need to say something that requires a verb after a preposition, you have to convert the verb into a noun.  Or rather, putting it more carefully, you have to nominalize the sentence that the verb occurs in.  The only ways to do that in English that retain the verbal status of the verb are to use the "Poss-ing" complementizer or the "for-to" complementizer.  Ignoring what happens to the subject of the sentence complement, that comes down to either adding "-ing" to the end of the verb or putting infinitival "to" in front of the verb.

So, here's an example of what happens.  The verb "decide" takes a following prepositional phrase complement to specify what is decided: "I decided on it". If "it" is an action describing me buying a purple shirt, I could say A. "I decided that I would buy a purple shirt", B. "I decided to buy a purple shirt", C. "I decided on the purchase of a purple shirt", D. "I decided on buying a purple shirt".

Notice that the "on" is lost in versions A and B, and the verb "buy" has been converted to a noun in C.  The only ways to fit a sentence into the structure demanded by "decide on" and at the same time keep the verb "buy" present are in B and D, and those have "to" before the verb or "-ing" added to the end of the verb.

So all the possible exceptions to your rule of thumb have been eliminated, more or less by coincidence.

(I didn't realize this was going to be so involved when I started typing it out.)

Comment: The reported rule seems to me to be backwards -- like "grammar rules I heard of" so often are -- in that it attempts to predict what **must** happen in general terms, while considering just a few cases of what **can** happen in specific terms. Instead of documenting alternatives, it prohibits random patterns.